# What do I misunderstand about passing a pointer as a parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++03

I've written a few hundred line long program in C++. It's my first real program and I'm trying to extend its feature set.

However, I'm getting stuck up on passing a pointer as a parameter.

I thought that you could just have one of the parameters as begin a pointer to a certain type of object, but my code that follows gives the error below:

Function call:

```
if (count(dvector.begin(),dvector.end(), "TO") > 0 ) {

    vector<string> dvector;

    map<string, vector<string> > params_map ;

    dvector = change_named_params(dvector, params_map);
}
```

Function signature:

```
vector<string> change_named_params(vector<string> to_check,
                                   map< string, vector<string> > * params_map) {/* body */}
```

Error message:

> ```
> ../Stack_interface.cc: In function ‘void
> execute_user_function(std::string)’: 
> ../Stack_interface.cc:451:52:
> error: cannot convert ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>,
> std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >’ to
> ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::basic_string<char>
> > >*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > change_named_params(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >,
> std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::basic_string<char>
> > >*)’    dvector = change_named_params(dvector, params_map);}
> ```

What am I messing up?

Comment: Maybe start with five or six lines that work?

Comment: The declaration of your function expects a pointer and you are passing it an object.

Comment: Why do you declare `dvector` that shadows `dvector` in the enclosing scope? Your call passes empty vector to `change_named_params`.

Comment: Ahh okay, I was originally passing it as I should have been, but I was getting an unrelated std::bad_alloc error thrown that I misattributed to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `change_named_params` takes in a pointer to a `map<string, vector<string>>` whereas you are only giving it the map. Call it instead like `change_named_params(dvector, &params_map);`. The `&` in front will get the memory address of the variable.

Another solution would be to take in a reference instead of a pointer. (making your function be `return-type name(type& name)` will make it take in a reference to a `type`, but you can access it exactly like normal.

Comment: I'm a lot more used to iterators in other languages, so I've been over-relying on pointers when it's possible I should have been using references. I originally passed the parameter as you suggest here, but blamed an unrelated error on it. I'm going to work on changing my function to take references rather than pointers and reevaluate how I understand both. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a pointer.  Instead, use references like this:

```
vector<string> change_named_params(vector<string> & to_check, map< string, vector<string> > & params_map)
```

If you don't need to modify the parameters inside your function, make them `const` references.

References, like pointers, allow you to pass objects to functions without copying them.  But references allow easier syntax than pointers.